# How to Tokenize a String and Save Each Substring Separately (Independent Names for Each Substring)

Tags: c++

I am given two files one with the name of person and the location that they are from
(Evan Lloyd|Brownsville)
and one with the name and salary (Evan Lloyd|58697) (the line number that you find the employee on in the first file is not necessarily the line number that find the employee on in the second).
The user inputs a location (whole or part). For example if they input "ville" or "Ville" it should include all of the employees in Brownsville, Clarksville, Greenville, etc. I am supposed to join the the name and salary and return them if they are in the city searched for i.e. "ville" or "Ville." I am attempting to use a vector for both of the files
vector(name, address) and vector(name, salary) and later return a vector of a string and tuple (address, (name, salary)) as my output. I don't know how to tokenize the string for example "Evan Lloyd|Brownsville" into the substrings "Evan Lloyd" and "Brownsville" separately (without the |) and save them separately so that I can push both strings into my vector(name, address). How would I tokenize the strings that way or should I try something else entirely?

Comment: This question isn't really a good match for StackOverflow, since SO normally prefer you to ask much more specific questions. For example, you could try some solution and then ask about a specific implementation issue. Dividing a string into two pieces like that is extremely simple: take a look at `str::find` and `str::substr` for one solution.

Comment: @rici Okay, for substr in this code (apologies for formatting)                             
    // Take any string 
    string s = "dog:cat"; 
    // Find position of ':' using find() 
    int pos = s.find(":");  
    // Copy substring after pos 
    string sub = s.substr(pos + 1); //returns cat                                                                         would string sub = s.substr(pos-1); return dog?

Comment: No, `s.substr(pos-1)` is the string starting at position `pos-1` ("g:cat"), just like `s.substr(pos+1)` is the substring starting at position `pos+1`. You need `s.substr(0, pos-1)`. I'm sure your reference material is clear, at least about that :-). (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr, for example). But this site is *not* for programming questions, elementary or otherwise. Try [so].

Comment: @rici What is this site for?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic